# Using avicap.dll to open settings

Tags: c++, video, webcam

I am using avicap.dll and I want to open the settings of the camera.
My code is:

```
mCapHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA(
             "WebCap1", 536870912, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height, 0, 0);
int i = SendMessage(mCapHwnd, 1034, 0, 0);
int j = SendMessage(mCapHwnd, 1066, 0, 1);
```

but, the advanced tab is opened.

I want the source settings to be opened on load.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

What you know as `1066` is actually `WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOSOURCE`. So you are basically doing [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOSOURCE message displays a dialog box in which the
>   user can control the video source. The Video Source dialog box might
>   contain controls that select input sources; alter the hue, contrast,
>   brightness of the image; and modify the video quality before
>   digitizing the images into the frame buffer. You can send this message
>   explicitly or by using the capDlgVideoSource macro.

This opens you one of the four possible dialogs associated to the capture device, read about the other three on MSDN, `WM_CAP_DLG_*` messages: [Displaying Dialog Boxes to Set Video Characteristics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797890%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi, I dont understand how to use it. can you please give an example? what should I declare? thank you

Comment: MSDN gets you a code snippet: "Displaying Dialog Boxes to Set Video Characteristics" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797890%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I want to open only the source settings tab and not all the rest. can it be done? thank you

Comment: Did you check the link above with code snippet, `capDlgVideoSource` in particular?

Comment: yes.. I cant make it work as I want.. this method doing the same as :"SendMessage(mCapHwnd, 1066, 0, 1); " do you know how can I get only the settings?